Can we obtain any information from the rotating motion of the dipole?
When a distribution of electric charges rotates, it generates an electromagnetic field, which can interact with a magnetic dipole to induce rotational motion. Is there any relation between the rotational motion of these two, i.e. distribution and dipole? I was wondering if we can find the frequency of the rotation of source from the frequency of the dipole motion.
If there is, can we extend this behavior to wave from classical non-linear theories such GR?

see https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8457248/references#references OR the mechtenna and references therein https://doi.org/10.1109/APUSNCURSINRSM.2017.8072780

The precession frequency of the dipole depends on its dipole moment as well as on the strength of the magnetic field. The moment of the dipole has nothing to do with the rotation of the charge distribution.
